# Datalist from python list

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to generate a datalist on my website that comes from a list on python.

My html file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input list="hschools" name="hschool">
  <datalist id="hschools">
    {% for elem in hsch %}
        <option value= {{elem}}>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And is saved in trying.html

My main.py file is:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    hsch=["a","b","c"]
    return render_template("trying.html")

if __name__=="main":
    app.run()
```

I then try to run the web-app and I do not get anything. Can you see my error? 
 Maybe I am not running it correctly... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`render_template` needs `hsch` to be passed:

```
return render_template("trying.html", hsch=hsch)
```